# Applying css on submenu issue

Tags: html, css

This is the html code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top parent">
        <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>level1a</span></a>
            <ul class="level0">
                <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first">
                    <a href="#"><span>level1b</span></a></li>
                <li class="level1 nav-1-2"><a href="#"><span>level1c</span></a></li>
                <li class="level1 nav-1-3"><a href="#"><span>level1d</span></a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level0 nav-2 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>level2a</span></a></li>
    <li class="level0 nav-3 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>level2b</span></a></li>
    <li class="level0 nav-4 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>level2c</span></a></li>
    <li class="level0 nav-5 level-top"><a href="#" class="level-top"><span>level2d</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When i hover on the level1a I want to display the submenu. how can i do that?

css code:

```
.main-menu ul li ul{display: none;}
.main-menu ul li:hover{/* that part I don't know */}
```

Comment: Please add css as well. Add code through snippet.

Comment: can you share demo link?

Comment: can you add your css code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
.main-menu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
 .main-menu ul li:hover > ul{
        display:block;
    }
```